# Is there any way to read a large(18 GB) XML file of unknown structure from the last to first

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to read an XML file of large size(18 GB) using iterparse() function, and I have to write the elements as a CSV file. Works well for the first instance, but after sometime, the system is getting freeze. I used element.clear(). still processing very slowly. I have done almost half, so, is there any steps to read that file from the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Use SAX (instead of DOM). This will handle the fact that you have a very big file to parse.

What you will have to implement is a 'ContentHandler' that will write the data to csv.

See Example below:

```
import xml.sax
from xml import sax


class ExampleContentHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        xml.sax.ContentHandler.__init__(self)

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        print('start:', name)

    def endElement(self, name):
        print('end:', name)

    def characters(self, content):
        print('chars:', content)

def main():
    xmlString = "<note>\n<to>Tove</to>\n<from>Jani</from>\n<heading>Reminder</heading>\n<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n</note>"

    sax.parseString(xmlString, ExampleContentHandler())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Balderman, I am trying not to use SAX for this. Any other ideas,please?

Comment: Why not using SAX?